# Spring Data MongoDB applying unique index transitively on parent object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring MVC application I have the following Mongo entities:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserMongoEntity {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @NotBlank
  @Email
  @Indexed(unique = true, sparse = true)
  private String email;

  private String firstName;
```

and a Submission entity containing User as a field:

```
@Document(collection = "submissions")
public class SubmissionMongoEntity {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private Instant timestamp;

  @Valid
  private UserMongoEntity user;
```

When I make a request to insert a new User, I get an error if a user with the same email already exists, as expected. However, when I insert a submission with the same user twice, I get an exception for violating the uniqueness of the index: `duplicate key error collection: user.email dup key`.

I could remove the `@Indexed`, but I believe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way to "disable" uniqueness for nested documents.
as answered in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277313/mongodb-unique-field-inside-a-nested-array-of-object-in-a-collecction)  mongo indexes main purpose is to speedup certain queries and less so about data validation.

if you do still want to keep the uniqueness one work around i could think off is exploiting mongo's [unique compound index and missing values](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field) .
create a unique compound index for email + a null field for user.
while insert a submission set that user null field to be unique (either time hash or a unique submission id)
thus creating a unique compound index that would not clash.